# Evaluate the integral: $\int 2 \cos^4 5x dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate
$$\int 2 \cos^4 5x dx$$

For this I know we would use the double angle identity $\cos^2 x = \frac 1 2 (1+\cos 2x)$.

But I'm having difficulty setting up the problem.

Comment: Yes, that will work. Using the identity once, you get that your integrand is $1+\cos^2(10x)$. Now use the identity once more to  "simplify" the $\cos^2(10x)$ term.

Answer (score 1):

From the double angle identity, $$\cos^45x=\left(\frac{\cos{10x}+1}{2}\right)^2$$

Then just repeat this with $\cos^210x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int 2 \cos^4 5x dx=\int ({1+\cos^2 10x})dx=\\
x+\int \dfrac{1+\cos 20x}{2}dx=1.5x+0.5\int \cos(20x)dx=\\
\dfrac{3}{2}x+\dfrac{1}{40}\sin(20x)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Since I am on a bit of different wavelength,

$$\begin{align}z=e^{5ix}&\implies \cos(5x)=\frac{z+\frac{1}{z}}{2}\\&\implies \cos^4(5x)=\frac1{16}\left(z^4+4z^2+6+\frac{4}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z^4}\right)\\&\implies 2\cos^4(5x) = \frac18\left(2\cos(20x)+4\cos(10x)+6\right)\end{align}$$

Complex numbers make everything shorter.